# Scope variable how to access in jasmine framework using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I injected controller all dependencies into spec.js file and trying to access the scope variable but am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'itemsByPage' of undefined` spec.js file mocked below;

```
`describe('baseController', function() {
 beforeEach(module('seApp'));
 var $controller,$scope,$compile, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log, 
 $http,$uibModal, $routeParams, $window,$mdDialog;
 inject(function($controller,$rootScope,$compile, $timeout,$mdSidenav, 
 $log, $http,$uibModal, $routeParams, $window,$mdDialog){ 
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile = $compile,
        $timeout  =$timeout,
        $mdSidenav =$mdSidenav,
        $log = $log,
        $http = $http,
        $routeParams = $routeParams,
        $window = $window,
        $mdDialog =$mdDialog,
        $uibModal = $uibModal;
        baseController = $controller('baseController', {
            $scope : $scope,
            $compile : $compile,
            $timeout  :$timeout,
            $mdSidenav :$mdSidenav,
            $log : $log,
            $http : $http,
            $routeParams : $routeParams,
            $window : $window,
            $mdDialog : $mdDialog,
            $uibModal : $uibModal
        });
    });  
 it('check the base controller', function() {
   expect(1).toBe(1);
 });
describe('check scope', function() {
it('check itemsBy page', function() {
  expect($scope.itemsByPage).toEqual('8');
}); });});`
```

execution report is `Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED)` controller is passing but not able to access scope variable inside the controller. please suggest me am new for jasmine framework

Comment: Replace `inject(...)`  by `beforeEach(inject(...))`

Comment: if I add like this beforeEach(inject(...)) am getting error like `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:`

Comment: Then you need to do the same thing as with every error: read it, understand why you get it, and fix the code accordingly. It starts by "read it". You haven't posted it, so we can't help you with that.

Comment: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$HashMapProvider <- $$HashMap <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile`

Comment: You're probably using incompatible versions of angular modules. Make sure they all have the same exact version.

Comment: ok let me check all version

Comment: Thanks its version problem now its working fine